# How to create table from PDO in yii2?

Tags: php, pdo, yii2, yii-components

Hy guys,
How to create table in PDO yii2?
this code in my controller

```
$db = new yii\db\Connection([
        'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=mydata',
        'username' => 'local',
        'password' => 'bukapeta',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ]);


 $commandR = "CREATE TABLE mencoba(nama_tempat TEXT ,tanggal TEXT ,waktu TEXT ,alamat TEXT ,jenis_tempat TEXT ,keterangan TEXT ,foto_lokasi TEXT ,latitude TEXT ,longitude TEXT ,tanggal_buat TEXT ,update_terakhir TEXT ,pembuat TEXT);"
 $command = $db->createCommand($commandR);
 $command->execute();
```

[image]

but this error
please help me..

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Your problem is right there in the error message: `Class 'Yii\db\Connection' not found`. You should try replacing those backslashes ("\") with forward slashes ("/")...

Comment: try: `new \yii\db\Connection` -> see the leading slash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `$db->open()`

```
$db = new \yii\db\Connection([
    'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=mydata',
    'username' => 'local',
    'password' => 'bukapeta',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
]);
$db->open();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `createTable` of the `queryBuilder`.
For example :

```
$queryBuilder = rows = (new \yii\db\Query());
$sql = $queryBuilder->createTable('myTable', [
    'id' => 'pk',
    'myColumn' => 'string',
    'myOtherColumn' => 'number'
]);
```